# Evaluate $\sum _{ n=1 }^{ \infty }{ { (-1) }^{ n+1 } } n^{-1/2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I know that $\sum _{ n=1 }^{ \infty  }{ { (-1) }^{ n+1 }\frac { 1 }{ n } =\ln(2) }$ .

How about the series $\sum _{ n=1 }^{ \infty  }{ { (-1) }^{ n+1 } } \frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { n }  }$

To what number does it converge?

Comment: To a real one, of course.

Comment: Let's be constructive, @user72694

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the function $\eta(s)=(1-2^{1-s})\zeta(s)$, where $\eta(s)=\sum (-1)^{n+1}n^{-s}$ and $\zeta(s)=\sum n^{-s}$.

Letting $s=1/2$, we can write $\eta(1/2)=(1-\sqrt{2})\zeta(1/2)=0.60489864\ldots$
I do not believe there is a more simple/elementary closed form.

Comment: Maybe add a proof of the eta-zeta identity (which is not difficult)?

Comment: Also, this particular $\zeta(s)$ is hardly $\sum n^{-s}$ :-)

Answer (score 1):

We can put this into [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+1+to+infinity+of+%28-1%29%5E%28n%2B1%29%2an%5E%28-1%2F2%29) and see $$-(\sqrt{2}-1)\zeta(\frac{1}{2})\approx 0.6048986$$
where $\zeta$ denotes the [Riemann zeta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function).